# What do directory names '.' and '..' mean and what does faDirectory mean?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have got a procedure which searches for a file entered by the user in a path and subpaths, i have a good understanding of the most of it except for this line:

```
if ((Rec.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0) and (Rec.Name<>'.') and (Rec.Name<>'..')
```

The whole procedure is as follows, help would be appreciated as im not sure exactly of the purpose of this line of code, is it checking something in the subpath?.

```
procedure TfrmProject.btnOpenDocumentClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
FileSearch('C:\Users\Guest\Documents', edtDocument.Text+'.docx');
end;

procedure TfrmProject.FileSearch(const Pathname, FileName : string);
var Word : Variant;
    Rec  : TSearchRec;
    Path : string;
begin
Path := IncludeTrailingBackslash(Pathname);
if FindFirst(Path + FileName, faAnyFile - faDirectory, Rec) = 0
then repeat Word:=CreateOLEObject('Word.Application');
  Word.Visible:=True;
  Word.Documents.Open(Path + FileName);
   until FindNext(Rec) <> 0;
FindClose(Rec);


if FindFirst(Path + '*.*', faDirectory, Rec) = 0 then
 try
   repeat
   if ((Rec.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0)  and (Rec.Name<>'.') and (Rec.Name<>'..') then
     FileSearch(Path + Rec.Name, FileName);
  until FindNext(Rec) <> 0;
 finally
 FindClose(Rec);
end;

end; //procedure FileSearch
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) The [faDirectory](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_faDirectory.html) attibute indicates whether the entry is a directory.

```
 (Rec.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0 //check if the current TSearchRec element is a directory
```

2) Each directory has two [Dot Directory Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ac44452-328c-4d7b-a784-d72afd19bd9f%28v=prot.13%29#dot_directory_name), which must be avoided in the recursive scan.

```
(Rec.Name<>'.') and (Rec.Name<>'..') //check the name of the entry to avoid scan when is `.` or `..`
```

In other words that line means: only scan if the current entry is a directory and is not a `Dot Directory`.

Comment: so (Rec.Attr and faDirectory) returns a negative value if it the current TSearchRec element is a directory? why is this

Comment: No, the line `(Rec.Attr and faDirectory)` uses the `AND` operand to check if the `faDirectory`($00000010) value is set in the attibutes of the entry.

Comment: i see, thanks a lot. I know that this was not the original question i should technically create a new question, but i was wondering if you have the time whether you could suggest to me how i could have a showmessage to indicate that i file has not been found, i have attempted to put a boolean variable where the variable FileFound is set to false, but FileFound := true if FindFirst(Path + FileName, faAnyFile - faDirectory, Rec) = 0, however being a recursive procedure this wont work, any easy methods of achieving it?

Comment: You can have `FileSearch()` return a `Boolean` indicating whether it finds the file on any given iteration.  Once an iteration returns `True`, keep passing `True` up the recersive chain to the original caller. FYI, on XP and later, there is a `SearchPath()` function available that searches for a filename in a specified path so you don't have to search manually anymore.

Comment: i've done this and it works except for the fact that when the showmessage comes up and i press ok it keeps reappearing even though ive got it at the end of the procedure